# only one required input in set of generated inputs

Tags: jquery, required, parsley.js

I'm having a set of inputs where I can add or remove them in any number > 1. I need always one and any of this field to be required. But I don't know how to achieve this in the most effective way. For now my first field is required and when I add the copy of it to the list I just removed the  `required` attribute:

```
var newInput = $(previousInput)
               .clone(true)
               .attr('id', '--id_' + cloneCount)
               .removeAttr('required');
newInput.appendTo($(div));
```

but each of these fields may be removed by corresponding `remove_button`. So when the input with `required` attribute there will be none left. What's more then every time the same field would have to be filled in while I would like to any if these be enough. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: You can check on submission for the input to be there instead of using require attribute

Comment: I'm using parsley validation. Could you give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: If you're asking for a way to do something in a specific library, be sure to tag your question with the tag for that library. 
Also, this seems to be a very similar (if a little old) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526654/parsley-validator-at-least-one-field-is-required